# How to connect React Oauth to Nest Oauth Google

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, nestjs, google-oauth, passport.js

I've setted up a google strategy with passport in nestjs. This allows the user to sign in with google, and then receive an access token.

Here is my endpoints:
Controller

```
@Get('google')
  @Public()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
  async googleAuth(@Req() req) {}

  @Get('redirect')
  @ApiOkResponse()
  @ApiUnauthorizedResponse({
    description: 'Wrong password.',
  })
  @ApiNotFoundResponse({
    description: 'User with this email not found.',
  })
  @Public()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  async googleAuthRedirect(@Res() response: any, @Req() req) {
    const accessToken = await this.authService.signInWithGoogle(req.user);
    return response.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(accessToken);
  }
```

So my backend NestJs is localhost:8000
When I go to localhost:8000/google, I'm redirected to a sign in with Google, and then when it's done i'm redirected to /redirect and receive access_token
That works perfectly fine.

But I want to add a React Frontend, let's say localhost:3000

And in this frontend, have a login with Google button, and when I click on it, I' redirected to google sign in, and then I can log the access_token.

How can I do that ?

I've tried:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Header } from '../components/Header';
import { LoginForm } from '../components/LoginFormComponent';
import { GoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';
import axios from 'axios';

const Login = () => {
  const handleGoogleLoginSuccess = async (response: any) => {
    console.log(response);
  };

  const handleGoogleLoginFailure = () => {
    console.error('Google login error');
    // Gérer les erreurs de connexion ici
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Votre contenu de connexion */}
      <GoogleLogin
        onSuccess={handleGoogleLoginSuccess}
        onError={handleGoogleLoginFailure}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

but I'm not redirected to my backend, just to a signin with google, and then I've credentials in my log.
But my backend is not called.

What Should I change ?
I've my app.tsx that contains google setup
and on google console cloud uri accepted redirection is localhost:8000/redirect

thanks in advance !!

Comment: You already set up Google OAuth in the frontend. The only thing you need to do is send a request to Nestjs (in `handleGoogleLoginSuccess`). something like creating a user in your own application.

Comment: but I've setted up on google Oauth the callback url (my backend), is'nt supposed to be automatic ?